# Foreign Keys vs Joins

Tags: sql

Is it better to use foreign keys in tables or can the same results be achieved with joins?

Comment: What is the difference? Joins are defined using foreign keys only. Of course, you might not define the foreign key in the database. Using foreign key will better the performance (provided the foreign key selection is right).

Comment: `Joins are defined using foreign keys only` False!  `Using foreign key will better the performance` Also false.  In fact, if anything, FK's can hurt performance, though only rarely to any noticeable degree that justifies removing then.

Comment: @Kangkan creating FK have nothing to do with performance FK != Indexes. There are DBMS automatic creates a index in the FK creation but most don't. Joins don't need FK please refer to excellent Daniel answer. Maybe OP is confused by ORM frameworks

Comment: **primary-key, foreign -key** are used to maintain **data consistency**. If u want data from more than 1 tables in single query, then u can use **JOINS**. So Joins is independent on PK-FK relationship.

Comment: @MechaCode So it sounds like we need both - FK and Join - if we want to combine data from multiple tables?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

[Foreign keys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) are just constraints to enforce [referential integrity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_integrity). You will still need to use [JOINs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_join) to build your queries.

Foreign keys guarantee that a row in a table `order_details` with a field `order_id` referencing an `orders` table will never have an `order_id` value that doesn't exist in the `orders` table. Foreign keys aren't required to have a working relational database (in fact [MySQL's default storage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MyISAM) engine doesn't support FKs), but they are definitely essential to avoid broken relationships and orphan rows (ie. referential integrity).

Comment: I just want to point out that although FK are cool, it is rather poor design to *rely* on the DB for the application logic. Your application may break without updates to your database(multiply by installations). May as well minimize it.

Comment: @sims: I don't consider "referential integrity" as application logic. The ability to enforce referential integrity at the database level is required for the C in [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) to stand.

Comment: @sims: I agree with Daniel, but would like to extend his reasoning. IMO RI is part of business logic (or 'data logic') it has to be enforced somewhere (ONCE, don't repeat yourself). Since the DB is the central/final data authority, the data must be valid there, hence his point invoking ACID is correct!

Comment: DRY ACID... yummy... Not using FKs doesn't cause a problem. Abstract the database access. You are better off doing it this way if you have to cater for databases that do not support FK or SP or views or whatever. I'm all for data integrity and tidy DBs. But I also favour portability and maintainability.

Comment: @sims: abstracting the DB access assumes you can enforce the db will only be accessed by that abstraction or interface. In my experience this is not enforceable. "data want's to be free / code craves to have errors". Best to delegate RI to the DB, bake it into the ERD. DRY ACID, yum indeed :-)

Comment: I believe the question was about foreign keys in general, and not about foreign key constraints. This answer discusses foreign key constraints.

Answer (score 30):

**`FOREIGN KEY`s** and **`JOIN`s**  don't do the same thing!

- A **`FOREIGN KEY`** enforces data integrity, making sure the data conforms to some rules when it is added to the DB.
- A **`JOIN`** is used when you extract/query data from the DB by giving rules how to select the data.
- `JOIN`s work if there are FK or not.
- FK's work if you extract data with or without `JOIN`s.

**CONCLUSION:** FK and `JOIN` don't allow you to achieve the same goal!

Comment: To add to that, **FKs** ensure that you don't have stale data in your tables.  Thus, inner **JOINs** will work better with **FKs**.

Comment: I believe the question was about foreign keys in general, and not about foreign key constraints. This answer discusses foreign key constraints.