# join, foreign key and other relational DB planning

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, data-binding

I am new to database planning and in programming in general.

I need to develop desk app for realtors. 
It needs to have at least 2 tables:

**property_table** - id, license #, address, city, bedrooms, baths, laundry, etc, etc.

**image_table** -  id, picture_name, path, size (image related DB)

(it will probably need a agent_table, but lets keep things simple).

*Property_table* will have only *one*  address per ID. A new entry with same address has to generate new ID (a person re-selling same house).

But *image_table* may have 10 entries for the same property address. 
I am using PHP Session to bring address, city, zip code between table to avoid mistakes from user (therefore *image_table* is actually id, picture_name, path, size, address, city, zip code, username).

**QUESTION**: should I use a foreign key? Or just join in my searches? Many questions about this, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947440/foreign-keys-vs-joins), good [tutorials](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) on joins, [etc.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-using-joins.htm), [etc](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp). It seems I have to use join query. What about the foreign key?

WHY: I need to show the listings  like    coming from different BD. Address (table-1) has several pictures (table-2).

PLANNING AHEAD. In the long term, same address will have more than one entry (same address, same zip code).

Just confused with so much new information and trying to plan ahead. 
Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: yes - the picture row will have a pointer over to which property it is a picture of. this pointer is the FOREIGN_KEY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

property_table - Property_table_id(PK), license #, address, city, bedrooms, baths, laundry, etc, etc.

image_table - image_table_id(PK),Property_table_id(FK), picture_name, path, size (image related DB)

Select * from property_table PropTable
Inner Join Image_Table imgTable on PropTable.Property_table_id = imgTable.Property_table_id

Answer (score 0):

In general I would say 'yes' to using the Foreign Key (FK).  I am just assuming that since you are using PHP that you are probably using one of the many popular free or open source databases such as MySQL for your relational database back-end.  Having the FK will allow you to set constraints on your data, to prevent you from making a mistake that may cause your program to error out.

For example, in your scenario you have the `property_table` table, which will have several addresses, in which some of them may use the same images.  In this case, you would want a column in your `property_table`, maybe `property_table`.`image_id` that is a a FK to your `image_table` table, referencing the column `image_table`.`id`.

If you set up your constraints properly on the FK, you will prevent yourself from accidentally entering the `id` of an image in the `images_table` table that does not exist.  You can also use constraints to automatically manage the references for you in case you do something with the data in refered (`images_table`) table.  For example, if you delete the image from `images_table` you could have all references to that image automatically set to NULL (an empty value) inside the `property_table`.

Comment: Thank you for your time. Yes, PHP/MySql (phpMyadmin). Wouldn't be better to have foreign key on image_table? We may have many properties with one pic (my guess: in a new condo development having many condos but showing the same staged kitchen), but for sure many pics for the same address.

Answer (score 0):

Foreign key is a **constraint**, JOIN is a query method. While it is true that JOINs are often (but not always) done "on top" of foreign keys, they are not the same thing.

- So, if you need to ensure there are no "dangling pointers" (as you do between `image_table` and `property_table`), use foreign key. Always enforce the data integrity at the database level, even if you also enforce it in the UI<sup>1</sup>
- If you need to get the related data from two (or more) tables using a single query, use JOIN.

---

*<sup>1</sup> Which will protect your data in case of bugs, especially subtle concurrency bugs that almost certainly exist in your code unless you employed locking very carefully. Furthermore, if you ever have to create another application that accesses the same database, it will benefit from integrity constraints that are already there. And if you ever modify the data ad-hoc through the generic UI provided by your DBMS, it will be more difficult to "break" the data.*

Comment: Thank you for message. I am new to database and I actually had to read this (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_integrity) to have an idea on data integrity. So much to learn...